# How to get nth- parent element in pure javascript and not jquery

Tags: javascript

For example,

```
<div class="panel">
   <div class="inner-panel">
      <button onclick="hideParentElement()">
        Hide
      </button>
   </div>
 </div>
```

If I want to add a class to the outer most division, I need to fetch that element and add a class to it. How can this be achieved using pure javascript?

I have tried the following:

```
this.parentElement.parentElement.classList.add("classname");
```

This works but if there are more than 2 parentElements it is not the right way.
Please suggest a better way

Comment: You can loop trough the parentElements, but which parent do you need to add a class to? The one with "panel" class?

Comment: Yes "panel" class, but is there any other built in functions in javascript instead of looping parent elements??

Comment: but why you not use jquery

Comment: Because according to the req, whole page should have customized code, no plugins or external files can be included.

Answer (score 4):

In case when your class list is changing dynamically:

```
let parent = this.parentElement;

while (!parent.classList.contains('panel'))
    parent = parent.parentElement;

parent.classList.add('classname');
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to cycle the parents like this.

```
var el = this.parentElement;
while(el.className != 'panel'){
    el = el.parentElement;
}
//el is now your parent
el.className += "classname";
```

With pure Javascript this is the way to do it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply, but I just found a work around, element.closest(".panel") gives the parent element with class "panel".

Comment: I think that solution, @VarshaBommarabettu, might also give you a sibling or child.

Comment: @VarshaBommarabettu your solution is actually correct, and API Docs state that only ancestor are considered (so siblings and children should not be a problem).
Please do note, though, that Internet Explorer doesn't support the `closest` method, and requires a polyfill to work (the required polyfill is actually the code I posted above).

Answer (score 0):

Kind of late to the party, but this seems to work:

```
var pn = element.parentNode
for(i=4;i>0;i--){
    pn = pn.parentNode;
}
```